# Docker can reach network

Tags: python, node.js, docker

I have need to reach an api that is on an other computer of my network 
I do this in a container using nodeJS it works, i can access the api, 
I do this in a contaienr using python i can't access the api,

I start my docker with :

```
docker run -d --name containername --net=host -p 502:80 image:0.0.8
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ip/api/v1/Configuration/ProductVersion/$value , that's the url i need to reach from container, 
I manage to reach it inside nodejs container i don't manage inside python container.
My purpose is to reach it inside python container

Comment: Seems to be more a python problem than a docker problem. Can you show the code for the python server ?